# Create dynamic php function and run it later - Save it to a variable

Tags: php, function, variables, dynamic

Im trying to make a function to run it later.

In php 5.3.2-1 it works fine. But in 5.1.6 it doesn't.

The code is:

```
$func = function(){                                                             
  echo "Hello!";                                                                
};                                                                              

echo "Before Hello";                                                            
$func();
```

Does anyone knows how to emulate this in 5.1.6?

Thanks.

Eduardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3. You cannot use them in older versions. Take a look at [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you know any patch that i can add to 5.1.6 in order to have this anonymous functions available?

Comment: @Edu: I do not think that you can simulate this behaviour using native PHP. You'd need to recompile PHP with support for anonymous functions (whis is probably not as easy as it sounds, since you need to do some heavy manual source-digging and -merging). It would be much easier to upgrade to a newer version of PHP.

Answer (score 6):

```
$func = create_function('','echo "Hello!";');

echo "Before Hello";
$func();
```

to be able to "assign a function to a variable", while not delving into eval-ish code:

```
function my_not_so_anonymous_function1()
{
    echo "Hello!";
}
$func = 'my_not_so_anonymous_function1';

echo "Before Hello";
$func();
```

Comment: I hate that eval-ish code, but this is the only workaround that i am aware of. +1!

Comment: Thanks. But that is a solution that is not good for me. I want to write a lot of code and i really don't want to create a function as string. Not good for later debug.

Comment: The question was how to emulate something that is not available. This is the most obvious answer. There is one alternative, hang on...

Comment: see my updated answer. I'm still going for that checkmark ;-)