# function name must be a string PHP

Tags: php

I get this error when I try to call the function func_connect_mssql.

Here is my code:

```
    $func_connect   = 'func_connect_mssql';
    $session = $func_connect($serv, $user, $pass, $base) 
or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>");
```

as you can see func_connect is a variable that I'm using to call the function that's why I used the "$func_connect", I tried to change that and put directly the name of my function but still returns the same error on the second line.

Comment: try: $session = $$func_connect(

Comment: "i tryed to change that and put directly the name of my function" You tried `func_connect_mssql($serv, $user, $pass, $base)`? That should work.

Comment: Are you sure, that the error is at `$func_connect(...)` and not at `$func_error(...)`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: isn't it better to use derived classes and make use of polymorphism in your case?

Comment: I have to say, this isn't a good way of doing things. Just write the function names!

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584419/create-dynamic-php-function-and-run-it-later-save-it-to-a-variable

Comment: You first need to understand what the error message means. Also you need to find the exact location where that error happens. It's easier when you place that line over multiple lines (hint, hint :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this : [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
$func_connect   = 'func_connect_mssql';
$session = call_user_func($func_connect,$serv, $user, $pass, $base) or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>");
```

Comment: Why? Isn't that exactly the same that's already done with the variable functions? http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: This works OK:

function func_connect_mssql($serv, $user, $pass, $base) {

  return 1;

}

function errrr() {

  return 'asas';

}

$func_connect = 'func_connect_mssql'; 

$func_error = 'errrr'; 

echo $func_connect('s', 'd', 'f', 'sa') or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>");
die();

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhat misleaded by your own code:

```
$func_connect   = 'func_connect_mssql';
$session = $func_connect($serv, $user, $pass, $base) or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>");
```

Instead you should at least wrap that over multiple lines:

```
$func_connect   = 'func_connect_mssql';
$session = $func_connect($serv, $user, $pass, $base)
    or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>")
    ;
```

The error message then will tell you in which line the error occurred. You will be amazed to learn that it is at a different position than you currently think it is.

As you code looks a bit fragile, you might want to add some safety net as well from time to time:

```
$func_connect   = 'func_connect_mssql';

is_callable($func_connect)) or die('Connection Function is not callable!');
is_callable($func_error)) or die('Error function is not callable!');

$session = $func_connect($serv, $user, $pass, $base)
    or die("<p class='Perror'>&middot;Failed - err Connect: ".$func_error()."</p>")
    ;
```

Comment: +1 one, and I deleted my answer bsaed on your astute comment :)

Comment: i used call_user_func as Fluffeh suggested but still same thing, so hakra you mean that the problem doesn't come from the call of the function?

Comment: @cascadox: I put two alternative ways how to write the code in the answer. Play around with those (type them, don't copy them) and you should learn what a bit more where your problem is located. That does not mean that it solves your problem already, however locating it is a precondition.

Comment: @cascadox Hakra is showing you how to halve your troubleshooting by eliminating one of the two sections of code is *not* the culprit.

Comment: According to the error message it is not a string. Another friend for trouble shooting is `var_dump()` - You can use it to look into variables. Also never view in the browser shiny display the error messages, but inside the source-view of your browser.

Comment: yes so i tryed to change the second part and use call_user_func($func_error) but now it's just returning and impossible to connect... anyway i'll look for the problem

Comment: You just spent a medium sized answer saying absolutely nothing at all